# Override compareTo() method in custom Java class?

Tags: java, arraylist, interface, compareto

I have both a Dog and Cat class which look something like this:

```
public class Dog implements Speakable
{
private String name;

public Dog(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public void speak()
{
    System.out.println("Woof! Woof!");
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Dog: " + name;
}

}
```

These classes both implement an interface I have created called Speakable which looks like this:

```
public interface Speakable
{
  public void speak();
}
```

This Speakable interface exists because I need a reference variable that allows me to add Dogs and Cats to the same ArrayList and still invoke the speak() method on them.

I also need to override the compareTo() method of the Comparable interface so I can compare the names of dogs. When calling this method, I think my code will look like this: a.compareTo(b). I want this new method to return -1 if a is greater than b, 1 if a is less than b, and 0 if they are equal.

I think I need the Dog class to specifically implement Comparable in addition to Speakable so the Comparable interface I have written is this:

```
public interface Comparable<Dog>
{
    public int compareTo(Object obj);
}
```

How do I override the compareTo() method to meet the needs I listed above? I know I will need several if statements, but I can't think of a way to write this without calling the compareTo() method within the new compareTo() method. Is that legal? Shouldn't the compareTo() method from the comparable interface already contain these decisions?

Comment: "How do I override the compareTo() method to meet the needs I listed above" - what are your needs. I can see that you want to compare only name

Comment: What do you mean by `a is greater than b, a is less than b`? How do you compare `dog`s?

Comment: You are trying to sort your List<Speakable> ? Or a List<Dog> ?

Comment: You are not supposed to create your own `Comparable` interface. That's why it's generic - each class can implement it for itself.

Answer (score 3):

Remove your custom `Comparable`, and use the Java [`Comparable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). And you could modify `Speakable` to [extend](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/nogrow.html) `Comparable`. Something like,

```
public interface Speakable extends Comparable<Speakable>
```

Then every `Speakable` is also a `Comparable<Speakable>`

Comment: When I do this, I get an error that says Dog is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(speakable)

Comment: You'd have to override `compareTo(Speakable)`. If you want to be able to compare `Cat`s and `Dog`s.

Answer (score 2):

Use Java Comparable interface in **Dog** class. Somenthing like this:

```
public class Dog implements Speakable, Comparable<Dog>{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Dog o) {
        return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
```

}

Comment: Error: Cannot find variable name when I write it like this.